# Python: Modify and edit a dataframe inside a function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Tester1': ['A','B','C','A','B','E','F','A','E','B','C','C'],
                    'Tester2':['D','A','E','A','B','F','F','A','B','B','A','C'],
                    'Day':['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2'],
                    'Value':['-0.94','0.48','-0.79','-0.46','-1.02','0.31','-2.21','-2.1','-0.86','0.52','-0.23','0.71']})
```

I want to do the following steps:

- a) Look at the data by day. For instance first look at `Day == 1`
- b) Sort the subset of the data by descending order of `Value`
- c) Take the `Tester` pair with highest value and append it to a list and save for future use (Note that the pairs of testers can be same or different. e.g. Tester A and Tester B or Tester A and Tester A.
- d) Remove all data from the subset which contains **either** (Thanks @smci) Tester 1 **or** Tester 2 with the highest Value.

Repeat steps c),d) until all the observations for a particular day is done. Repeat until all the days in the dataset is done.

My current code:

```
day_list=list(set(d2['Day']))
data_list=[]
for day in day_list:

    # Creating subset of the data for days in the day_list - (Step a)

    data_per_day=d2[d2['Day']==day]
    for i in range(len(data_per_day)):

       # Sorting the data in descending order by value 

        sorted_data_per_day=data_per_day.sort_values('Value',ascending=False)

       # Taking the top observation and appending it to  data list - (Step b & c)

        zz=sorted_data_per_day.iloc[0,:].to_frame().T
        data_list.append(zz)

       # Creating a list of testers in the data which was stored - (Step d)

        tester_list1=(zz['Tester1'].iloc[0],zz['Tester2'].iloc[0])
        tester_list=list(set(tester_list1))

        # Removing all observations which contain Tester 1 or Tester 2 - (Step d contd.)

        sorted_data_per_day1=sorted_data_per_day[~sorted_data_per_day['Tester1'].isin(tester_list)]
        sorted_data_per_day2=sorted_data_per_day1[~sorted_data_per_day1['Tester2'].isin(tester_list)]
        sorted_data_per_day=sorted_data_per_day2

data_list2=pd.concat(data_list,axis=0)
```

An example of the output for `Day == 1` is as follows:

For step a) & b) - Subset of data taken and Values are sorted

[image]

For step c) Take the tester pair with the highest value

[image]

For step d) Remove all Tester pairs containing either A or B.

[image]

Repeat all the above steps with this new observation set.

Right now, what I get is as follows:

[image]

**I have a gut feeling that I made a mistake in these two steps of the code:**

i) `for i in range(len(data_per_day)) # Should I change this to a while loop?`

ii) `sorted_data_per_day=sorted_data_per_day2 # Really not sure why this list is not getting updated`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Please let me know if any part is not clear here. I will update them.**

**Edit:**

I have also tried the following but the output does not change:

```
sorted_data_per_day = data_per_day.sort_values('Value',ascending=False)
    for i in range(len(sorted_data_per_day)):
```

Comment: Step d) is ambiguous: Do you mean *"Additionally, remove all data from the subset which contains (BOTH?) Tester1 AND Tester2 with the highest Value"*? or *"which contains EITHER Tester1 OR Tester2"*?

Comment: @smci Yes. Remove the observations which contain either Tester1 or Tester2. I have updated my original question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Ok then you don't need the *"Remove the top observation from step c)"* since it will be covered when you *"Remove all data from the subset which contains EITHER Tester1 OR Tester2"*

Comment: @smci Exactly. I will modify the original question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Also when you say *"[Remove] the Tester pair with highest value and append it to a list and save for future use"*, generally we don't need to remove and append stuff like that from grouped dataframes, we can just descend the sorted list of values, and exclude Testers we've already seen, and we can set some integer/boolean flag in an extra column to say which rows our algorithm is taking. (Do you only want to store the Testers, or also that whole row including the Value?)

Comment: Glad we solved it. Can you edit to change the title to something more appropriate? (Better to describe *what* you want to do than one specific implementation of how, esp. when it's not good practice to modify a df, and not even opssible inside a function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of steps a),b),c) with a simple `groupby().apply(...)`, at least for the first pass:

```
df.groupby('Day').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Value', ascending=False).head(1))

       Tester1 Tester2 Day Value
Day                             
1   1        B       A   1  0.48
2   11       C       C   2  0.71
```

We can just select the columns we need, drop the index, and return as a list/set/whatever you want; you can adapt this code:

```
df.groupby('Day').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Value', ascending=False).head(1)[['Tester1','Tester2']] )
       Tester1 Tester2
Day                   
1   1        B       A
2   11       C       C
```

Step d) was ambiguous, but you clarified it reduced to *"Remove/Ignore all other entries in this Day group which contain EITHER Tester1 OR Tester2 from step c)"*

Simplest is probably to keep a `set` of testers, initialize it to all testers for that day and remove testers (`set.discard()`) when we see those testers occurring on top-valued entries. When either we've run out of entries or testers, processing that day is finished.

Also when you say "[Remove] the Tester pair with highest value and append it to a list and save for future use", generally we don't need to remove and append stuff like that from grouped dataframes, we can just descend the sorted list of values, and exclude Testers we've already seen, and we can set some integer/boolean flag in an extra column to say which rows our algorithm is taking. (Do you only want to store the Testers, or also that whole row including the Value?)

For example, here's code that gets the tester(s) from the top record in each `Day` group, as a list:

```
>>> df.groupby('Day').apply(lambda grp: grp.sort_values('Value', ascending=False) [['Tester1','Tester2']].iloc[0].tolist() )
Day
1    [B, A]
2    [C, C]
```

Anyway you can adapt this, you'll want to write some iterative function that goes inside your `apply()` call on a group, that returns e.g. some output dataframe e.g. with one extra column `Keep`, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with steps a-c. For step d - Remove the data which contains either Tester1 or Tester2. @smci

Comment: I figured it out. Changing the for loop to a while loop gets me the answer. I am accepting you answer since your comments helped a lot. Thanks again @smci

Comment: Great. If you're able to clarify the other ambiguities, I'll revisit the answer. In pandas you can't edit (remove/append/insert) a grouped dataframe or one you're iterating over. So instead of that, add an extra column (e.g. integer/boolean) to mark which rows your algorithm wanted to store. Call it `Keep` or whatever you like. The code you run inside the `apply(...)` on each group can be some iterative function you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here as well just in case someone else faces a similar problem in the future. Changing the for loop to a while loop helped.

```
#Incorrect code
for i in range(len(data_per_day)):

###########################    
#Correct code
###########################
while len(sorted_data_per_day)>0:
```

The output that I get now is shown below and this is exactly what I was looking for.

[image]